# haskell all function

Tags: list, haskell, boolean

I need a program that checks if the difference between all pairs of elements is in the interval from -2 up to 2 `( >= -2 && < 2)`. If it is, then return `True`, else return `False`. Foe example, `[1,2,3]` is `True`, but `[1,3,4]` is `False`.
I am using the `all` function. What is wrong with my `if` clause?

```
allfunc (x : xs)
   = if all (...) xs
      then allfunc xs
      else [x] ++ allfunc xs
allfunc _
   = []
```

Or I am doing something completely wrong?

Comment: You should note that this combines using a continuation, and using something which you could probably write better as a fold.

Comment: Is the order relevant? what's the output for [-2,0]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, it's probably easier to use list comprehensions or do-notation.

```
pairsOf lst = do 
  x <- lst
  y <- lst
  return (x, y)
```

`pairsOf` returns the list of pairs of numbers in the input `lst`. For example, `pairsOf [1,2,3]` results in `[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]`.

Now, you can define the difference between a pair in a one-liner `\(x, y) -> x - y` and map that over the list:

```
differences lst = map (\(x, y) -> x - y) (pairsOf lst)
```

Now you just have to make sure that each element in `differences lst` is between `-2` and `2`.

Of course, this is just one possible way to do it. There are many other ways as well.

Comment: One could probably simplify and do something like: `diffs lst= [ (x - y) | x<-lst, y<-lst]`, then push the result list of differences into `checkDiffS = all (\x-> x<2 && x>-2)`

Answer (score 2):

The naive way to do what you describe is:

```
allfunc xs = all (<=2) [abs(a-b) | a <- xs, b <- xs ]
```

However, a more efficient method would be to compare the minimum and maximum of the list:

```
fastfunc [] = true
fastfunc xs = maximum xs - minimum xs <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply...

```
allfunc xs = (maximum xs - minimum xs) <= 2
```

Or if you really want to investigate every pair, you can use monads:

```
import Control.Monad
allfunc xs = all ((<=2).abs) $ liftM2 (-) xs xs
```

`liftA2` from `Control.Applicative` would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem specification isn't very clear.

You say:

> the diffence between all elements is in interval from -2 till 2 ( >= -2 && < 2)

But also:

> Foe example, [1,2,3] is True, but [1,3,4] is False

How is it True for [1,2,3]?

Assuming you mean `-2 <= diff <= 2`, then I would use this:

```
allfunc :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> Bool
allfunc theList = all (\x -> (x >= -2) && (x<2)) [x-y | x <- theList, y <- theList ]

allfunc [1,2,3] -- => True
allfunc [1,3,4] -- => False
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, yes you're doing something wrong. `all` is meant to take a predicate and a list of values to test. So it will return `True` if and only if all values yield true when applied to the given predicate function. I.e.:

```
allValuesEven = all even
allValuesOdd  = all odd
```

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect: `[]` does not match the pattern `x:xs`.